# Error in Jupyter notebook even after importing the required library

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, conda, data-analysis

I'm getting an NameError in jupyter notebook even after importing numpy as np. Any idea how to go about it will be appreciated

```
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 300)
for i in range(2, 6, 2):
    plt.plot(x, np.sin(np.pi*x)*np.sin(2*i*np.pi*x))
```

**Error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 x = np.linspace(0, 1, 300)
      2 for i in range(2, 6, 2):
      3     plt.plot(x, np.sin(np.pi*x)*np.sin(2*i*np.pi*x))

NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

Comment: Have you checked if numpy is [installed](https://numpy.org/install/)? Type `conda install numpy` if using Anaconda, or `pip install numpy` if using Python.

Comment: Try importing libraries at top then %matplotlib inline

Comment: Check if numpy is installed. Then import matplotlib first before the %matplotlib inline

Comment: Close voting as typo. The output (`Input In [1]` and `<cell line: 1>`) indicates that the cell with imports was not run prior to running this cell, hence why `np` is not defined.